# php could not use $$ with array

Tags: php

I know that

```
$b = 1;
$var = "b";
$$var = 2;
echo $b;
```

will show 2

But when I try it on array, it fail

```
$c[1] = 1;
$var = "c[1]";
$$var = 2;
echo $c[1];

$d[1] = 1;
$var = "d";
$$var[1] = 2;
echo $d[1];
```

they both show 1, why?

Comment: You can't use variable variable for array indices, just for variable names.

Comment: Please tell me why you do this?

Comment: I just want to know what $$ really do

Comment: Oh, okay. You show it yourself. You set $var to 'b' and $$var to 'foo', so it means that you've set $b with 'foo'. Normally, do $b = 'foo'; is more efficient, more readable.

Comment: yes, but if it just replace the $var with "b", so $$var translate to $b, then when $var = "c[1]", should $$var also directly translate to $c[1]?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your first example, you can't use the index because it is assumed part of the variable name.

In the second, you need to use the curly braces for a complex syntax to disambiguate.  This way PHP knows that it's the contents of `$d[1]` and not the contents of `$var[1]`.

```
$d[1] = 1;
$var = "d";
${$var}[1] = 2;
echo $d[1];
```